# python igraph edges as nodes graph

Tags: python, igraph

I have a graph in igraph :

```
import igraph as ig
vertices = [i for i in range(7)]
edges = [(0,2),(0,1),(0,3),(1,0),(1,2),(1,3),(2,0),(2,1),(2,3),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(2,4),(4,5),(4,6),(5,4),(5,6),(6,4),(6,5)]
g = ig.Graph(vertex_attrs={"label":vertices}, edges=edges, directed=True)
```

But I'm wondering if there is something already implemented in Igraph in order to get the graph with edges as nodes of the actual g graph as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken this transformation is called a line graph,
Igraph python have function call linegraph().

I believe this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Like Romain said, you can do the trick with `linegraph()`.

```
import igraph as ig

vertices = [i for i in range(7)]
edges = [(0,2),(0,1),(0,3),(1,0),(1,2),(1,3),(2,0),(2,1),(2,3),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(2,4),(4,5),(4,6),(5,4),(5,6),(6,4),(6,5)]
g = ig.Graph(vertex_attrs={"label":vertices}, edges=edges, directed=True)

# Graph g with edges as nodes
g = g.linegraph()
```